# What are the common errors that would cause a generated rig to forget one arm?

Tags: rigging, error, rigify

I seem to be having an issue once I've generated the rig. It applies controls for the left arm with no problem, but nothing for the right arm.
I've tried a new project, I've tried deleting the arms in edit mode and symmetrize-ing, that just generated a rig with zero arm controls.
I'm wondering if there is anything else that might cause this so I don't have to re-do the metarig...or if I've hidden something?

Blender 3.4.1 - Can supply project file if needed.

[image: viewport display]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the Metarig, go to pose mode, select the first bone of the arm (upper_arm.R) and check if its "Rigify type" is set to "limbs.arm".

If this doesn't solve the problem, consider that enabling "vertex snapping", which works for bones joints also, snapping a new Metarig onto the old one is a matter of seconds.

[image]

Comment: Absolutely solved it, thank you so much!